# Mollifying the Heaviside function in MATLAB.

Tags: real-analysis, matlab

I'm a MATLAB newbie having trouble writing a program to mollify the Heaviside function. I've been looking all over the place and asking around, including at Stack Overflow, but I've had no luck. I know that this isn't *exactly* the place for a MATLAB question, but I've had good luck here before. If there is another place where this question would be more appropriate, please let me know.

At any rate, I'm trying to mollify the Heaviside function using the bump function $$
   \phi(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       e^{-1/(1-x^2)} & : \ |x| < 1\\
       0 & : \ |x| \geq 1
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

If $\Phi$ is the normalized version of $\phi$ and $h(x)$ is the Heaviside function, I'm trying to write code to approximate the integral $$\Phi_{\epsilon}(x) = \epsilon^{-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Phi\left(\frac{x-y}{\epsilon}\right)h(y) \ dy$$

To that end, I have written the nested function `smooth` in MATLAB:

```
function s = smooth(x,y,e)  
s = e.^(-1)int(mbump(x,y,e), x = -2..2);  
mbump(x,y,e)

    function m = mbump(x)
    m = cbump(x,y,e).*heaviside(y);
    cbump(x,y,e)

        function c = cbump(x,y,e)
        c = nbump(quot(x,y,e));
        nbump(t)
        quot(x,y,e)

            function n = nbump(t)
            n = bump(t)*(ibump(t)).^-1;
            ibump(t)

                function i = ibump(t)
                i = integral(@bump, -2, 2);
                bump(t)

                    function b = bump(t)
                    region1 = abs(t) = 1;
                    b(region2) = 0;
                    end

            function q = quot(x,y,e)
            q = (x-y)./e;
            end

            end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Also, please forgive my formatting. The definition of `smooth` should be to the left of the body as should the final `end`. It's like this in my code, but I don't know how to get the formatting right here.

This probably isn't the most elegant way to implement this function. Anyway, when I try and run `plot(x, smooth(x,y,e))`, I get the error `Unexpected MATLAB expression.` I know there must be something wrong with how I'm trying to integrate and I've tried several different ways, all of which don't work. Anyway, any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `x=-2..2` is not a MATLAB expression.

Comment: Use blockquote to reformat the code please. Start every line by `>`.

Comment: also you need explicit multiplication `*` after `e^(-1)`

Comment: I've never used blockquote before. Do I need to use many `>`'s to maintain the nested structure: >>>>>>? I don't quite understand the blockquote instructions.

Comment: Also, I got the n `x=-2..2` from the MathWorks website. What notation should I use if I want to integrate `mbump(x,y,e)` with respect to `y` from -2 to 2?

Comment: re-read the documentation for `int` (and put a link if you have questions). But keep in mind that's for symbolic integration. I recommend you simply bin your x-axis and sum it up (numerical integration). Sorry about the blockquote thing, I don't think it worked out for you.

Comment: I updated your code block with `<pre></pre>` tag (under peer review). http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks for the reformatting. I've changed `s = e.^(-1)int(mbump(x,y,e), x = -2..2);` to `s = e.^(-1)*integral(@mbump,-2,2);`, but now it gives the error `Undefined function 'quot' for input arguments of type 'double'.`

Comment: Also, how do I ensure that I'm integrating with respect to the correct variable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10785/discussion-between-memming-and-alexander-sibelius)